# Is there a method in SQL Server to import JSON as a file update it and export as a file without creating table?

Tags: json, sql-server, database, crud, geojson

I have to edit this JSON from specific folder using SQL Server without creating or storing it to a specific table

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "Location",
    "features": [
         { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Code": 60102091.0, "SDCName": "Phoksundo HP", "SDC_Type": "DOTS", "LA_ID": 60102, "Pradesh": "Karnali Pradesh", "District": "Dolpa", "Name_LA": "Shey Phoksundo", "Type_LA": "Gaunpalika", "Ward_Num": 9, "DR": 0, "SDR": 0, "GeneX": 0, "MC": 0, "DOTS": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 82.9144, 29.14394, 0.0 ] } },
         { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Code": 60101077.0, "SDCName": "Tinje HP", "SDC_Type": "DOTS", "LA_ID": 60101, "Pradesh": "Karnali Pradesh", "District": "Dolpa", "Name_LA": "Dolpo Buddha", "Type_LA": "Gaunpalika", "Ward_Num": 3, "DR": 0, "SDR": 0, "GeneX": 0, "MC": 0, "DOTS": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 83.171584990599797, 29.149520453581768, 0.0 ] }  },
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and what are the expected edits?

Comment: The real version that I use is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Comment: I want to edit the file located in some location like ' E:\district.json'  , I wish to update the '"DOTS": 1 '  and   '"coordinates": [ 82.9144, 29.14394, 0.0 ] ' @Zhorov